# Totem issue with youtube: gstreamer

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, totem, gstreamer

When trying to play youtube videos in Totem, I get this error:

> **GStreamer encountered a general supporting library error.**

When starting from the commandline, the actual error is is this:

> **Message Error:** GStreamer encountered a general supporting library error.   gstffmpegdemux.c(1255):
>   gst_ffmpegdemux_open ():
>   /GstPlayBin2:play/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin1/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin21/ffdemux_swf:ffdemux_swf1: "Input/output error"

There are several threads floating around other sites for this problem in 9.xx, but I'm on 10.10, and supposing the proposed updates are long propagated.

I have checked and the Gstreamer FFMPEG plugin is installed: everything is basically stock.

Comment: > The problem returns every time Google
> changes its mind about the YouTube
> API. [(from here)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/544660/comments/15) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Törzsmókus pointed out, [this is a known recurring bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/544660). Totem's Youtube interoperation is achieved by reverse-engineering the Youtube API. So whenever Google changes the API, Totem breaks. The bug is marked fixed, but if it reappears, file a bug or comment on Launchpad.